# Create text Files from every row in an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, file, text, rows

I need help creating separate text files from each row in an excel spread sheet called "worksheet".  I want the text files to be named with content of Column A, with columns B-G being the content, preferably with a double hard return between each column in the text file, so each column will have a blank line in between them.

Is this possible?  How would I go about it.  thanks!

Comment: In what language do you want to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@nutsch's answer is perfectly fine and should work 99.9% of the time.  In the rare occasion that FSO is not available, here's a version that doesn't have a dependency.  As is, it does require that the source worksheet doesn't have any blank rows in the content section.

```
Sub SaveRowsAsCSV()

Dim wb As Excel.Workbook, wbNew As Excel.Workbook
Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet, wsTemp As Excel.Worksheet
Dim r As Long, c As Long

    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("worksheet")

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'will overwrite existing files without asking

    r = 1
    Do Until Len(Trim(wsSource.Cells(r, 1).Value)) = 0
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        Set wsTemp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

        For c = 2 To 7
            wsTemp.Cells((c - 1) * 2 - 1, 1).Value = wsSource.Cells(r, c).Value
        Next c

        wsTemp.Move
        Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
        Set wsTemp = wbNew.Worksheets(1)
        'wbNew.SaveAs wsSource.Cells(r, 1).Value & ".csv", xlCSV 'old way
        wbNew.SaveAs "textfile" & r & ".csv", xlCSV 'new way
        'you can try other file formats listed at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa194915(v=office.10).aspx
        wbNew.Close
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
        r = r + 1
    Loop

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting a "400" error . . . I do have a couple of cells that are blank within the content . . . not sure if that might be the cause.

Comment: The macro stops when it encounters a blank cell in column A (because then the filename is blank, as per your instructions).  I have never encountered a 400 error, I just looked it up.  Is it possible some of those "blank" cells actually contain a string of spaces?  Also, what version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Strange, I tested in 2010, no issues.  Does the macro write any text files before the error?  I edited the line starting with Do Until, please try the macro with the new line there.

Comment: I am still getting the same "400" error.  i do see it "working" creating spreadsheets for each text file for a second.  The spreadsheet left open after the "400" error is the 2nd row which contains text in columns A-G.  Now I am thinking that the cause the problem could naming it by the content of the the first column . . . how about if name the text files by sequential numbers?  thanks!

Comment: I made some slight edits to create a specific reference to the new workbook, not sure if it will help.  Can you post the first few cells in Column A?  Are they acceptable as valid file names?

Comment: I don't think the titles are acceptable . . . in thinking about . . . the text in those boxes is way to long for file names

Comment: Re-edited to use sequential filenames. Keep in mind now that the text in Column A is being ignored... your question says the file contents are in columns B to G.

Comment: Awesome . . . that worked.  It stopped when it got my first entry without content in column A.  It worked fine on rows without info in other columns.  Now I just need to add some text to those missing entries in column A and I should be off to the races. Thanks!

Comment: @ExactaBox I am receiving a "Subscript out of range" error... using Excel for Mac 2011. Any thoughts? I'm trying to accomplish exactly what the OP is - filename from Column A (no blank rows) and content from Columns B-G.

Answer (score 3):

The attached VBA macro will do it, saving the txt files in C:\Temp\

```
Sub WriteTotxt()

Const forReading = 1, forAppending = 3, fsoForWriting = 2
Dim fs, objTextStream, sText As String
Dim lLastRow As Long, lRowLoop As Long, lLastCol As Long, lColLoop As Long

lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For lRowLoop = 1 To lLastRow

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objTextStream = fs.opentextfile("c:\temp\" & Cells(lRowLoop, 1) & ".txt", fsoForWriting, True)

    sText = ""

    For lColLoop = 1 To 7
        sText = sText & Cells(lRowLoop, lColLoop) & Chr(10) & Chr(10)
    Next lColLoop

    objTextStream.writeline (Left(sText, Len(sText) - 1))


    objTextStream.Close
    Set objTextStream = Nothing
    Set fs = Nothing

Next lRowLoop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for helping.  I might have done something wrong, but I am getting a "next without for" error.  Any ideas?

Comment: @nutsch I'm getting an error that reads "ActiveX component can't create objects"

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of others, I sorted the problem out. I replaced "Chr(10) & Chr(10)" with "Chr(13) & Chr(10)" and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I used the simple code below for saving my excel rows as a text file or many other format for quite a long time now  and it has always worked for me.

Sub savemyrowsastext()
Dim x

For Each cell In Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
' you can change the sheet1 to your own choice
        saveText = cell.Text
          Open "C:\wamp\www\GeoPC_NG\sogistate\igala_land\" & saveText & ".php" For Output As #1
          Print #1, cell.Offset(0, 1).Text
          Close #1
        For x = 1 To 3  ' Loop 3 times.
    Beep    ' Sound a tone.
Next x
Next cell
End Sub

Note:

 1. Column A1 = file title
 2. column B1 = file content
 3. Until the last row containing text (ie empty rows)

in reverse order, if you want to make it like this;

 1. Column A1 = file title
 2. column A2 = file content
 3. Until the last row containing text (ie empty rows), just change ***Print #1, cell.Offset(0, 1).Text***  to  ***Print #1, cell.Offset(1, 0).Text***

My folder location =  C:\wamp\www\GeoPC_NG\kogistate\igala_land\  
My file extension = .php, you can change the extension to your own choice (.txt, .htm & .csv etc)
I included bip sound at the end of each saving to know if my work is going on
 Dim x
For x = 1 To 3  ' Loop 3 times.
    Beep    ' Sound a tone.

Comment: Thank you, this did the job with a minor change: Print #1, cell.Offset(0, 1).Value2 instead of Print #1, cell.Offset(0, 1).Text. It seems that .Text only printed the first 1025 character instead of the whole text

Comment: @Igalapedia Project But what if you want to include all column's from column B > forward as content in the text file? Where would I change that variable?