# Write each Excel row to new .txt file with ColumnA as file name

Tags: excel, vba

I would be extremely grateful for any help as I have just begun to look into writing Excel macros.

I have excel documents with about 1,500 rows and variable column lengths, from 16-18.  I would like to write each row of the file to a new .txt file (actually, I would REALLY like to write it as a .pdf but I don't think that's possible) where the name of the file is the corresponding first column.  Additionally, I would like each row to be separated by a new line. So, ideally, the macro would 1) export each row as a new .txt file (or .pdf if possible), 2) name each file as ColumnA, 3) the content of each new .txt file would contain ColumnsB-length of total columns 4) each column is separated by a new line.

For example, if the document looks like this:

> column 1//column 2// column3
>
> a//a1//a2
>
> b//b1//b2

I want it to output to be 2 files, named "a", "b".  As an example, the contents of file "a" would be:

> a1
>
> a2

I have found 2 other stack overflow threads addressing separate pieces of my question, but I am at a loss as to how to stitch them together.

Each row to new .txt file, with a newline between each column (but file name not ColumnA):
[Create text Files from every row in an Excel spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077740/create-text-files-from-every-row-in-an-excel-spreadsheet)

Only one column incorporated into file, but file names correspond with ColumnA:
[Outputting Excel rows to a series of text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149539/outputting-excel-rows-to-a-series-of-text-files)

Thank you for any  help!

Comment: I tried to add bits of each example into the other, but I am not familiar with writing Excel macros (I know R, and that's about it).  I successfully used both examples, but the output was not ideal in either case (couldn't get the content to be columns B-end of file in the first case and have each column on a new line in the .txt file; file name was "text1", "text2", etc in the second case, although content was correct).  I just kept breaking the macro in my attempts to manipulate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the contents to be columns B thru the end of the file, you could do something like this.

Create a simple loop over the cells in Column B. This defines a range of columns for each row, and also sets a filename based on the value in column A.

```
Sub LoopOverColumnB()

Dim filePath as String
Dim fileName as String
Dim rowRange as Range
Dim cell as Range

filePath = "C:\Test\" '<--- Modify this for your needs.

For each cell in Range("B1",Range("B1048576").End(xlUp))
   Set rowRange = Range(cell.address,Range(cell.address).End(xlToRight))

   fileName = filePath & cell.Offset(0,-1).Value

   '
   ' Insert code to write the text file here 
   '
   ' you will be able to use the variable "fileName" when exporting the file
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input, I finally stitched it together with what I had before and have posted the resulting code.  It's not pretty, but thanks to your post it runs the way I need it to.  Thanks!

Comment: Cheers! Consider "accepting" or upvoting my answer if it's helped solve your problem :)

Comment: I can't upvote because I don't have enough reputation :/  I'll just accept it since it was key in putting the final product together.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up stitching the following together to solve my problem, thanks entirely to @David and @Exactabox.  It is incredibly inefficient and has redundant bits, but it runs (Very. Slowly).  If anyone can spot how to clean it up, feel free, but otherwise it gets the job done.

[edit] Unfortunately I now realize that although this macro exports each row as an appropriately named new .txt file, the content of each text file is the last row of the document.  So even if it exports all 20 lines as 20 .txt files with an appropriate file name and correct formatting, the actual content of each of the 20 files is the same. I am unsure how to rectify this.

```
Sub SaveRowsAsTXT()

Dim wb As Excel.Workbook, wbNew As Excel.Workbook
Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet, wsTemp As Excel.Worksheet
Dim r As Long, c As Long
Dim filePath As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim rowRange As Range
Dim cell As Range

filePath = "C:\filepath\"

For Each cell In Range("B1", Range("B1048576").End(xlUp))
   Set rowRange = Range(cell.Address, Range(cell.Address).End(xlToRight))

   fileName = filePath & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'will overwrite existing files without asking

    r = 1
    Do Until Len(Trim(wsSource.Cells(r, 1).Value)) = 0
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        Set wsTemp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

        For c = 2 To 16
            wsTemp.Cells((c - 1) * 2 - 1, 1).Value = wsSource.Cells(r, c).Value
        Next c

        wsTemp.Move
        Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
        Set wsTemp = wbNew.Worksheets(1)
        wbNew.SaveAs fileName & ".txt", xlTextWindows 'save as .txt
        wbNew.Close
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
        r = r + 1
    Loop

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This should fix the problem of getting the same data in all the files:

```
Sub SaveRowsAsTXT()

Dim wb As Excel.Workbook, wbNew As Excel.Workbook
Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet, wsTemp As Excel.Worksheet
Dim r As Long, c As Long
Dim filePath As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim rowRange As Range
Dim cell As Range

filePath = "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\TEST\"

For Each cell In Range("B1", Range("B10").End(xlUp))
    Set rowRange = Range(cell.Address, Range(cell.Address).End(xlToRight))

    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'will overwrite existing files without asking

    r = 1
    Do Until Len(Trim(wsSource.Cells(r, 1).Value)) = 0
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        Set wsTemp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

        For c = 2 To 16
            wsTemp.Cells((c - 1) * 2 - 1, 1).Value = wsSource.Cells(r, c).Value
        Next c
        fileName = filePath & wsSource.Cells(r, 1).Value

        wsTemp.Move
        Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
        Set wsTemp = wbNew.Worksheets(1)

        wbNew.SaveAs fileName & ".txt", xlTextWindows 'save as .txt
        wbNew.Close
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
        r = r + 1
    Loop

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't for the life of me get this to work. I get Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

Answer (score 0):

@danfo, I don't know if this will be useful to you, but after some fiddling, I did get this working. I needed to make sure that all my top row was written with no spaces or special characters; and my left column needed to be ID numbers, rather than dates or anything else -- but once I'd fixed those things, it worked fine.