# Extra Excel rows as separate files

Tags: vba, excel, osx-yosemite

I have an Excel spreadsheet with 1504 rows of html-marked up new stories. I need to extract these rows to individual files - the ultimate goal is to have them all saved as PDF files.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554099/write-each-excel-row-to-new-txt-file-with-columna-as-file-name/15665756#15665756) thread that discussing extracting Excel rows to TXT files.

I've tried to adapt the macro for my spreadsheet but I'm currently getting "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" and the process stalls out with the first row opened but not saved into a separate workbook.

None of the cells in the spreadsheet (screen cap below) have been renamed in anyway.

[Seven rows of an Excel spreadsheet with the headers News Post ID, News Title, Date Published, Date Unpublished, Author, Post Content - Description, and Post Content - Notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCCVY.png)

[image]

I am running OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 and Office for Mac 2011.

```
Sub SaveRowsAsTXT()

Dim wb As Excel.Workbook, wbNew As Excel.Workbook
Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet, wsTemp As Excel.Worksheet
Dim r As Long, c As Long
Dim filePath As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim rowRange As Range
Dim cell As Range

filePath = "/Users/sarah.gesell/Google Drive/Projects/News Stories/Test"

For Each cell In Range(("A2"), Range("A1504").End(xlUp))
    Set rowRange = Range(("A2"), Range("A1504").End(xlToRight))

    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'will overwrite existing files without asking

    r = 1
    Do Until Len(Trim(wsSource.Cells(r, 1).Value)) = 0
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        Set wsTemp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

        For c = 2 To 16
            wsTemp.Cells((c - 1) * 2 - 1, 1).Value = wsSource.Cells(r, c).Value
        Next c
        fileName = filePath & wsSource.Cells(r, 1).Value

        wsTemp.Move
        Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
        Set wsTemp = wbNew.Worksheets(1)

        wbNew.SaveAs fileName & ".txt", xlTextWindows 'save as .txt
        wbNew.Close
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
        r = r + 1
    Loop

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: -->> `Range(Range("A2"), Range("A1504").End(xlUp))`

Comment: I went from 

    For Each cell In Range(("A2"), Range("A1504").End(xlUp))
        Set rowRange = Range(("A2"), Range("A1504").End(xlToRight))

to

    For Each cell In Range(Range("A2"), Range("A1504").End(xlUp))
        Set rowRange = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A1504").End(xlUp))

But still got the same error and hang-up.

Comment: I'm having problems following your code - it might help to explain exactly what you want to do with each row in the source sheet.

Comment: I'm just starting to learn VBA so I don't actually know what each row does. The original post has the source of the code.

Comment: What do you *want* it to do though ?  How should your content be laid out in the txt file?

Comment: I want each row to be extracted and saved to a TXT or DOC/DOCX file. I don't know enough about VBA to be able to say much more.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me on PC (using a different path):

```
Sub SaveRowsAsTXT()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim filePath As String, id
    Dim rw As Range, content As String, c As Range, nl As String

    filePath = "/Users/sarah.gesell/Google Drive/Projects/News Stories/Test"

    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    For Each rw In wsSource.Range("A2:G1600").Rows
        id = rw.Cells(1).Value
        'if there's an ID write out this row
        If id <> "" Then
            content = ""
            nl = ""
            'build the file content
            For Each c In rw.Cells
              content = content & nl & c.Value
              nl = vbNewLine 'use newline to separate cells
            Next c
            'write the text file
            WriteTextFile filePath & id & ".txt", content
        End If
    Next rw
End Sub

Sub WriteTextFile(sPath As String, sContent As String)
    Dim F As Long
    F = FreeFile
    Open sPath For Output As #F
    Print #F, sContent
    Close #F
End Sub
```