# Outputting .csv rows to a series of text files

Tags: excel, csv, text-files

How to output .csv rows to a series of seperate text files?

I saw this link, and the approach should be similar..
[Outputting Excel rows to a series of text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149539/outputting-excel-rows-to-a-series-of-text-files)

Can anyone help me know the steps and if i should use excel and suggest the steps, to achieve the above results as in the link or otherwise. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you give a little more clarification on what your *exact* requirements are? Have you tried anything already?

Comment: The answer to the linked post should work perfectly, if you open that .csv in Excel.

Comment: I have 3 columns: A: Name B:Address C:Zipcode in .csv - I want to covert each row of the csv into a seperate text tile and the content in the columns  to become the ''title of the .txt file with a space in between each column text' and generate one seperate .txt file for each row in bulk. I use openoffice calc and don't know what to put in the functions or the steps to accomplish this...

Comment: I could open it in excel (calc in openoffice) and save it also. Where do i place/ run the code? thanks ZX9

Comment: Well, if it was really Excel, I'd tell you to start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737%28v=office.14%29.aspx). I don't know OpenOffice, but it looks like there are possibilities for [interoperability](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/VBA_interoperability_in_OpenOffice) with VBA... You'd probably be better off learning the OpenOffice language--[Basic](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide).

Comment: You *really* shouldn't tag this is as [excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel). That tag isn't intended for VBA (non-Excel formula-related questions). And, as you **must clarify in your question**, you're dealing with OpenOffice.

Comment: My advice is to see what you can find with `OpenOffice`, try running some code, and, if you have an issue, you can **edit** this question to cover all of that. And there's [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Welcome to StackOverflow! ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply ZX9. I saw this technique suggested by userid: 2596450 by igalapedia-project here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077740/create-text-files-from-every-row-in-an-excel-spreadsheet?answertab=active#tab-top

I have converted to excel, but don't know where to put this code that i given. Where should i execute it? under what menu function in excel?

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming you are actually using Excel now...**

First, like I said in one of my comments, you should start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to learn about using Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) on your own.

In Excel, it will be easiest to activate the <kbd>Developer</kbd> tab to access the the Visual Basic Editor.

1. Go to <kbd>File</kbd>><kbd>Options</kbd>><kbd>Customize the Ribbon</kbd>.
2. Check the Developer tab. Click Ok.
3. Go to <kbd>Developer</kbd> and under the `Code` section is <kbd>Visual Basic</kbd>. Click this to open the VBA editor.

Now you can make VBA subs. You can put them in specific sheets, the workbook as a whole, or modules in your `PERSONAL.XLSB` which allows any Excel workbook with macros enabled to run them.

You may need to create a module. If so:

1. Right-click on **`VBAProject (PERSONAL.XLSB)`**.
2. `Insert`>`Module`
3. Name it.

You can now paste code into the module and you have a "macro".

The easiest way to run this is to

1. Go to the <kbd>Developer</kbd> tab.
2. Hit <kbd>Macros</kbd>.
3. Select your macro.
4. Hit <kbd>Run</kbd>.

You can also assign a keyboard shortcut by hitting <kbd>Options...</kbd> in that same `Macros` menu.

Now you can essentially copy and paste the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149539/outputting-excel-rows-to-a-series-of-text-files). With a slight modification:

```
Sub Export_Files()
    Dim sExportFolder, sFN
    Dim rTitle As Range
    Dim rContent As Range
    Dim oSh As Worksheet
    Dim oFS As Object
    Dim oTxt As Object

    'sExportFolder = path to the folder you want to export to
    'oSh = The sheet where your data is stored
    sExportFolder = "C:\Disclaimers"
    Set oSh = Sheet1

    Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")

    For Each rTitle In oSh.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells
        Set rContent = rTitle.Offset(, 1) & ", " & rTitle.Offset(, 2)   '<--This will put in your Column B and C value. You can delimit with whatever you desire; I used a comma and space.
        'Add .txt to the article name as a file name
        sFN = rTitle.Value & ".txt"
        Set oTxt = oFS.OpenTextFile(sExportFolder & "\" & sFN, 2, True)
        oTxt.Write rContent.Value
        oTxt.Close
    Next
End Sub
```