# How to get content from all columns into text file from Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, notepad++

I am trying to export my excel data to individual text files for each row. I've looked at various SO questions already and can get a working result for each row but cannot get the content to be filled from all columns from column B and forward. Here is what I have tried.

This is from a VBA programming tut. It outputs all my columns but to only one file:

```
Sub toXPD()

Dim FilePath As String
Dim CellData As String
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

CellData = ""

FilePath = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\auth.csv"

Open FilePath For Output As #2

For i = 1 To LastRow

    For j = 1 To LastCol

        If j = LastCol Then
            CellData = CellData + Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value)
        Else
            CellData = CellData + Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value) + ","
        End If

    Next j

    Write #2, CellData
    CellData = ""

Next i

Close #2

MsgBox ("Done")

End Sub
```

I've also tried this from this SO question [Create text Files from every row in an Excel Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17729496/1055954) and it works for creating individual files for each row but only fills content from column B and not the others:

```
Sub savemyrowsastext()
Dim x

For Each cell In Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
' you can change the sheet1 to your own choice

    saveText = cell.Text

    Open "C:\wamp\www\GeoPC_NG\sogistate\igala_land\" & saveText & ".php" For Output As #1

    Print #1, cell.Offset(0, 1).Text

    Close #1

    Beep ' Sound a tone.

    Next x

Next cell
End Sub
```

I am extremely new to VBA/Macro coding and thought this would be a simple task. I've tried to piece together what was missing from the second set of code with pieces from the first set of code but nothing has worked. How can I get the second set of code to include all columns that have values as the content in each text file?

**EDIT: Per @Kumarapush additional answer**
The content does print on separate lines but outputs like so.

```
"columnB"
"columnBcolumnC"
"columnBcolumnCcolumnD"
```

**EDIT 2: This is the complete working code for anyone else that comes across this. It prints all columns from column B forward as the content of the txt file and column A as the title of each file. All thanks to @Kumarapush**

```
Sub toFile()

    Dim FilePath As String, CellData As String, LastCol As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim Filenum As Integer

    LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        FilePath = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value) & ".xpd"
        Filenum = FreeFile

        Open FilePath For Output As Filenum
        CellData = ""

        For j = 2 To LastCol
        CellData = Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Value)
        Write #Filenum, CellData

        Next j

        Close #Filenum

    Next i
    MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified few lines from your first sample code. It only missed some logic. Instead of writing to different files, It keeps on writing to same file.

Try the below code. I have tested it and it writes data from each row to a different CSV file.

```
    Sub toXPD()

        Dim FilePath As String, CellData As String, LastCol As Long, LastRow As Long
        Dim Filenum As Integer

        LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
        LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRow
            FilePath = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\auth" & i & ".csv"
            Filenum = FreeFile

            Open FilePath For Output As Filenum
            CellData = ""

            For j = 1 To LastCol
                If j = LastCol Then
                    CellData = CellData + Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Value)
                Else
                    CellData = CellData + Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Value) + ","
                End If
            Next j

            Write #Filenum, CellData
            Close #Filenum

        Next i
        MsgBox ("Done")
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it and it does create a different file for each row with content from all of the columns but I have a couple of questions that I should have mentioned in my OP. I apologize for not doing so. How would I get each file to be the value in column A and  have each column/content be on separate lines?

Comment: "How would I get each file to be the value in column A and have each column/content be on separate lines" - This is bit confusing. Could you please elaborate a bit on this? So, that a fix could be provided.

Comment: Yes. Although I think I figured out how to set the filename to be the value of column A, I just need to figure out how to fill the file with content from column B onward on separate lines. If you don't mind helping me with that. I'll check your answer as accepted regardless as it answered my OP. Again, I apologize if I am asking too much and for not including that in my original question.

Comment: I apologize but that's the same code that's already in your original post. All that does is print all the content on the same line separated by commas. For the format that I need each file to be in, the content needs to be on separate lines. I tried reading this SO post trying to figure out how they were doing it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13078475/1055954

Answer (score 2):

Replying the modification required as per your comment. i.e., To write each column data to separate lines in output file:
Not a problem Steve. Replace this code

```
    For j = 1 To LastCol
        If j = LastCol Then
            CellData = CellData + Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Value)
        Else
            CellData = CellData + Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Value) + ","
        End If
    Next j
    Write #Filenum, CellData
```

With this one

```
     For j = 1 To LastCol
            CellData = Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Value)
            Write #Filenum, CellData
     Next j
```

Comment: Steve, Please check my second part of code.I have modified the loop 'j'. I tested it &  It writes in different lines. Are you still facing problem?

Comment: Thank you very much!! It works! If I could I would kiss you right now! lol. I've been trying to figure this out for days. You're a life saver! Now I just gotta get the title of each file to be the value of column A. You're the best! Thank you again!!

Comment: would it be too much to ask how to set filename to value of column A? Like if column A row 1 is test and column A row 2 is test2, the outcome files would be test.csv and test2.csv. I've tried fileName = filePath & cell.Offset(0,-1).Value but I get an error when I run it. If you're able to help awesome, if not, no worries I appreciate all you've done for me.

Comment: Change this line: FilePath = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\auth" & i & ".csv"
into 
FilePath = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value) & ".csv"

Comment: Use this Line: 
FilePath = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value) & ".csv"

Comment: Thank you again!! Seems I'm exceeding the limit of comments here but if I could award you more rep points I would. You deserve it.