# Delete blank rows prior to saving text file in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the macro from the post [Create text Files from every row in an Excel spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077740/create-text-files-from-every-row-in-an-excel-spreadsheet) to create an individual file for each row in an Excel table. The output file is creating a blank row after each value. Can this code be modified so that blank rows are deleted prior to saving the file?

```
Sub SaveRowsAsCSV()

Dim wb As Excel.Workbook, wbNew As Excel.Workbook
Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet, wsTemp As Excel.Worksheet
Dim r As Long, c As Long

Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CSV_Template_Data")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

r = 1
Do Until Len(Trim(wsSource.Cells(r, 1).Value)) = 0
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set wsTemp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    For c = 2 To 142
        wsTemp.Cells((c - 1) * 2 - 1, 1).Value = wsSource.Cells(r, c).Value
    Next c

    wsTemp.Move
    Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsTemp = wbNew.Worksheets(1)
    wbNew.SaveAs "C:\Datasets\" & r & "_Well.csv", xlCSV
    wbNew.Close
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    r = r + 1
Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I was able to solve this one by using inserting the following code:         On Error Resume Next
            With Range("A1:A500")
            .Value = .Value
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
            End With

Answer (score 0):

Adding code to delete each empty row certainly works. changing:

```
wsTemp.Cells((c - 1) * 2 - 1, 1).Value = wsSource.Cells(r, c).Value
```

to

```
wsTemp.Cells((c) - 1, 1).Value = wsSource.Cells(r, c).Value
```

and then adding On Error Resume Next appears to work as well.